# react-router Cannot read property 'push' of undefined?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom

some code of index.tsx:

```
ReactDOM.render(
<MemoryRouter>
    <LocaleProvider locale={zhCn}>
        <App/>
    </LocaleProvider>
</MemoryRouter>,
document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement
);
```

some code of App.tsx

```
interface AppProps{
  history?: any
}
....
public route() {
    if (!session.isLogin) {
        this.props.history.push('/');
    } else {
        this.props.history.push('/root')
    }
}
...
public render() {
    return (
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path='/' component={Login} />
            <Route exact path='/root' component={Root} />
        </Switch>
    )
}
```

When I write this, I will report wrong.Cannot read property 'push' of undefined，Then I modified the use of "withRouter" to modify it.

```
export default withRouter(App)
```

Also reported wrong：
error TS2345: Argument of type 'typeof App' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ComponentType>'.

Type 'typeof App' is not assignable to type 'StatelessComponent>'.

Type 'typeof App' provides no match for the signature '(props: RouteComponentProps & { children?: ReactNode; }, context?: any): ReactElement | null'.

What is the problem?

Thank you

Comment: can you show how you use the <App/>

Answer (score 2):

Your `props` in `App.tsx` needs to extend `RouteComponentProps` from `react-router`

for example:

```
interface AppProps extends RouteComponentProps {
    // rest of props
}
```

You should then be able to use:

```
this.props.history.push("/your-route");
```

Comment: `interface AppProps extends RouteComponentProps{
    history: any
}`   It will still report mistakes. error TS2339: Property 'history' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<Component<Pick<AppProps, never>, any, any>> & Read...'.

Comment: You don't need to add ```history: any``` as part of your interface - it's part of ```RouteComponentProps```. How is your component declared?

Comment: `extends React.Component`

Comment: The first type param in your component should be ```AppProps``` i.e. ```extends React.Component<AppProps>```